# How to highlight with equal value between two table according two map value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had 2 tables like this table 1

[image]

and table 2

[image]

I want table 2 to be highlighted as if the value is correct.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below CF rule-

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$5=$E3)*($A$2:$A$5=F$2)*($C$2:$C$5=F3),0))
```

[image]